# Python with mvc - sqlite database instead of retrieving single row by id, retrieving whole table

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, model-view-controller

I have written the function that should retrieve some employee data from the database by using employee ID. Unfortunately, the function does retrieve data, but instead of one employee, it is retrieving the whole table. How I may fix it?

**Model**

```
    def get_employee_data_by_id(self, id):
    connection = sqlite3.connect("employees_database.db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""
        SELECT name, surname from employees WHERE ID = id"""), (id)

    data = cursor.fetchall()

    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
    return data
```

**Controller**

```
    def get_employee_data_by_id(self, id):
    data = self.model.get_employee_data_by_id(id)
    print(type(data))

    for i in data:
        self.view.employee_data.append(i)
        print(i)
```

**View**

```
    def show_frame1(self, event=None):
    self.main_frame.grid_forget()
    self.edit_employee_frame.grid()

    self.controller.get_employee_data_by_id(2)
```

Comment: Use `?` placeholder: `WHERE ID = ?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line (note that `(id)` is outside `cursor.execute(...)`):

```
cursor.execute("""
        SELECT name, surname from employees WHERE ID = id"""), (id)
```

should be changed to (using placeholder):

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT name, surname from employees WHERE ID = ?""", (id,))
```

Comment: Thank you.  Appreciate the help.